# expression to transform 'I' to 0

Tags: ssis

I have data ActiveNonActive columns in  and the data are A,I,Empty  I have Derived Column to transform data  to bit i or empty--->0 and A->1 just want to ask how to use expression   transform the 'I' for 0 
my expression

```
ISNULL(ActiveNonActive) ? (DT_BOOL)0 : (UPPER(ActiveNonActive) == "A" ? (DT_BOOL)1 : (DT_BOOL)0)
```

Comment: Your source data can have A, I, empty string and NULL. `A` becomes true, everything else is false. I ran each of those situations through your expression and they all evaluate as expected. Am I missing something in the question?